# How to stop a tkinter label from getting smaller?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-label

I am constructing a simple python program to make a window using tkinter with a background stored as an image on the computer.

- I first made a full-sized window and displayed it.
- I put a canvas on this window
- I then used the photoimage class and used my png image. I then put this on the label.
- At this point when I ran the code it worked perfectly.
- I tried to add a button on top the label and what happens now is that the label with the pictures shrinks and the picture is barely visible around the button.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui as pag


def act():
    print("Hey")
    ##action here
root = Tk()

winWidth, winHeight = pag.size()

root.state("zoomed")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=winWidth, height=winHeight, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
canvas.pack_propagate(0)

bgClass = PhotoImage(master=root, file="backg.png")

background = Label(canvas, image=bgClass, width=winWidth, height=winHeight)
background.pack()

b = Button(background, text="Click me", command=act)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I have tried using pack_propagate() to stop the label from shrinking, but it does not work.

Does anyone know how to stop the picture from shrinking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
bgclass=bgclass.resize((700,700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background = Label(canvas, image=bgClass)
background.pack()
```

Here I have resized image to 700x700 you can change according to your requirement.

Comment: Here I have answered according to your requirements if it does not work then also comment